# How to convert a JFrame Form file to a Java Class File

Tags: java

I am developing an application using Java Class files i.e. writing all the code for the components by myself which works fine. I want to add a `JFrame Form` file i.e. a file created with a source or text editor. The problem is when I call the `JFrame Form` from the Java Class File with a `button` or `menu item`, its not successful. So I realize the only way is to convert the `JFrame Form` file to a Java Class file. Is it this possible.

Comment: You need a program that turns your form into .java which you can compile. Netbeans has a tool for that. Swingbuilder is also a tool for that.

Comment: Can you give me the name of the tool and step by step guide to do that.